# How to append a line just one line before of previous text?

Tags: r

My data has a header "z" as below:

```
"       30.6716995239         0.0000000000         0.0000000000"
"       -6.3899497986        11.0677177090         0.0000000000"
"        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        34.1739006042"                                    
"Direct"
```

Now I want to add a line "System" just before the line of "Direct" as below:

```
"       30.6716995239         0.0000000000         0.0000000000"
"       -6.3899497986        11.0677177090         0.0000000000"
"        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        34.1739006042"                                    
"System"
"Direct"
```

I can add the line "System" below to the "Direct" by use of the following. But I can't add it before the line "Direct"

> cat(z, sep="\n",file = tmp) # sep="\n"
>
> cat('System\n', file=tmp, append=T)

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: What is your data? Is it a dataframe?

Comment: share a reproducible example of your data... you can use use `dput()`.

Comment: @SiddharthArthi: It's table of data. I'm finally save as:write.table(y, file = tmp, append=TRUE, row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = " ",quote = FALSE)

Comment: So you want to add new column ````System```` before the ````Direct```` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` to replace `Direct` with `System\nDirect` which will place `System` before `Direct`.

```
cat(sub("Direct", "System\nDirect", z), sep="\n",file = tmp)
```

Or use subsetting like:

```
cat(c(z[1:3], "System", z[-(1:3)]), sep="\n",file = tmp)\
```

Data:

```
z  <- c("       30.6716995239         0.0000000000         0.0000000000"
,"       -6.3899497986        11.0677177090         0.0000000000"
,"        0.0000000000         0.0000000000        34.1739006042"
 ,"Direct")
```